# Необходимо заменить строку в txt файле в случае, если она существует php

Tags: php

Требуется заменить строку в txt файле, если существует оная, имеющая nickname совпадающий с $nickname. Если строки не существует - создать её.
Собственно, вот мой говнокод, который не работает:

```
<?php
    $date_today = date("mdy");
    $today[1] = date("His");
    $file=file("listofplayers.txt"); 
    $open=fopen("listofplayers.txt","a");
    $has_nick = strpos($open, $_GET['nickname']);
    $replace=$_GET['x']." ".$_GET['y']." ".$_GET['z']." ".$_GET['skin']." ".$date_today.$today[1]." ".$_GET["playerColor"]." ".$_GET["nickname"]; # на что нужно изменить 
    if ($has_nick === true){
        $search = $_GET['nickname'];
        $string = array_search($search, $open);
        $line=$string+1; # строка, которую нужно изменить 
        for($i=0;$i<count($file);$i++) 
   { 
      if(($i+1)!=$line){fwrite($open,$file[$i]); 
      echo ("1");}
      else{fwrite($open,$replace."\r\n");
      echo ("2");}
   } 
    } else {
        fwrite($open,$replace."\r\n");
        echo ("3");
    }

    fclose($open);  
?>
```

Comment: `$_GET=['nickname']`? `$_GET('nickname')`? Что это за конструкции? "Не работает" - понятие растяжимое, поясните что именно вы ожидаете и что получаете?

Comment: Мне требуется изменить или добавить (в зависимости от наличия строки со значением, совпадающим с $_GET['nickname']) данные в listofplayers.txt. Получаю пустой файл (ныне он так же пуст). На ваши замечания обратил внимание, изменил облик этого убожества в сторону приличного вида $_GET['nickname']. Однако, по прежнему не работает. 

Сильно не ругайте, о php знаю только то, что он существует(